# How to change the signing identify for VS2022 App

Tags: google-play, visual-studio-2022

While the VS2022 Xamarin app can be built (prod and dev) I can no longer use the previous signing identity. So when I try upload the app to the Play Store I get an error that the certificate is wrong. (I no longer have the original identity). Can I update the cert in Play Store? Otherwise I have to upload the app as a new app with a different name.

Or how can I locate the key associated with the SHA1 fingerprint?